# How to see the query which called a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to know how was a stored procedure called. Meaning, with a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xsp_test_procedure
    @ParameterA INT,
    @ParameterB VARCHAR(5)
AS BEGIN
    code...
END
```

I'd like to insert into a table a log of how the procedure was called. Meaning, if it was called like: `EXEC xsp_test_procedure 5, 'abc'`, or like `EXEC xsp_test_procedure 2, NULL`, etc. So, I'd like to know with which parameters it was called.

I want this to be dynamic; this example only has 2 parameters, so it'd be easy to just read the parameters and turn them into a string, but I want to do this with several procedures, some with a lot of optional parameters.

I can get the server IP, the client IP, etc., but is there a way to get the query itself which called the procedure?

Comment: You'll need to put bespoke logging in your procedure to capture the parameter values, and store it *somewhere*. If you want to record details of queries, then look into Extended Events.

Comment: XEvents (Extended Events) is the way to go, you want the `sql_text` or the `stack_trace` values